# Sort dataframe in R (based on column values)

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I would like to semi-reversely sort a dataframe in R based on values (character) in a column.

I have the following sample dataset:

```
# Sample data
df <- read.table(text="id value
                 cx-01    1
                 cx-01    2
                 cx-02    1
                 cx-02    2
                 cx-02    3
                 cx-03    1
                 cx-03    2 
                 px-01    1
                 px-01    2
                 px-02    1
                 px-02    2
                 px-02    3
                 px-03    1
                 px-03    2
                 rx-01    1
                 rx-01    2
                 rx-02    1
                 rx-02    2
                 rx-02    3
                 rx-03    1
                 rx-03    2", header=TRUE)
```

Expected output:

```
      id value
1  cx-03     2
2  cx-03     1
3  cx-02     3
4  cx-02     2
5  cx-02     1
6  cx-01     2
7  cx-01     1
8  rx-03     2
9  rx-03     1
10 rx-02     3
11 rx-02     2
12 rx-02     1
13 rx-01     2
14 rx-01     1
15 px-03     2
16 px-03     1
17 px-02     3
18 px-02     2
19 px-02     1
20 px-01     2
21 px-01     1
```

I tried to use base R's `order()` function, but sadly without succes. Furthermore, I tried to use the arrange function of the `plyr` package, however, I did not manage to order the data as desired.

Is it possible to sort the labels in the first column based on a self-provided sequence (so not alphabetically)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `arrange` on the numeric and the letters part of 'id' separately, along with arranging the 'value' in `desc`ending order.  The letter part seems to be custom order, so either convert to `factor` with `levels` specified or use `match` with a `vector` in the same order as the expected to get the index in that order

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%  
   arrange(match(str_remove(id, "-\\d+"), c("cx", "rx", "px")), 
          readr::parse_number(as.character(id)), desc(value))
#      id value
#1  cx-03     2
#2  cx-03     1
#3  cx-02     3
#4  cx-02     2
#5  cx-02     1
#6  cx-01     2
#7  cx-01     1
#8  rx-03     2
#9  rx-03     1
#10 rx-02     3
#11 rx-02     2
#12 rx-02     1
#13 rx-01     2
#14 rx-01     1
#15 px-03     2
#16 px-03     1
#17 px-02     3
#18 px-02     2
#19 px-02     1
#20 px-01     2
#21 px-01     1
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `with()` and `order()` from base `R`

```r
# sample data
df <- read.table(text="id value
                 cx-01    1
                 cx-01    2
                 cx-02    1
                 cx-02    2
                 cx-02    3
                 cx-03    1
                 cx-03    2 
                 px-01    1
                 px-01    2
                 px-02    1
                 px-02    2
                 px-02    3
                 px-03    1
                 px-03    2
                 rx-01    1
                 rx-01    2
                 rx-02    1
                 rx-02    2
                 rx-02    3
                 rx-03    1
                 rx-03    2", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=F)

# create another data frame with variables to order on
col.ord <- data.frame(t(sapply(strsplit(df$id, "-"), print)), df$value, stringsAsFactors = F)

# reorder data frame
df[with(col.ord, order(X1, -as.integer(X2), -df.value)), ]
#>       id value
#> 7  cx-03     2
#> 6  cx-03     1
#> 5  cx-02     3
#> 4  cx-02     2
#> 3  cx-02     1
#> 2  cx-01     2
#> 1  cx-01     1
#> 14 px-03     2
#> 13 px-03     1
#> 12 px-02     3
#> 11 px-02     2
#> 10 px-02     1
#> 9  px-01     2
#> 8  px-01     1
#> 21 rx-03     2
#> 20 rx-03     1
#> 19 rx-02     3
#> 18 rx-02     2
#> 17 rx-02     1
#> 16 rx-01     2
#> 15 rx-01     1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>